# PHP class def: Individual accessors/mutators or __set() with switch()?

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

When defining a PHP class, which is preferred/best practice? Are there any key differences I'm overlooking?

It seems like it could be more clean, concise, and convenient to write a `__set()` magic method and put a `switch()` construct in it with cases for all the private members to which I want to allow access. It wouldn't be called automagically from inside the class, but then again neither would `setFoo()`, so if I want to use the accessor/mutator internally, I'd have to explicitly call a method either way.

The other difference is that in the code outside the class, I could always access member vars in the same fashion as `$obj->foo`, whether public (directly) or private (using `__set()`), versus using many separate methods.

I guess this comes down mostly to an aesthetic choice. For example, if I have address data on a purchase, I don't want to have 16 or more separate accessor methods just for first name, last name, address1, address2, city, state, etc. each for shipping and billing data.

Are there any key differences I've overlooked? (Might a sophisticated IDE refuse to auto-complete a member name outside the class because it's marked as private?) Have I pretty much answered my own original question? Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go with the individual accessors for each and every member you want to be accessible from outside. I have tried both and found these reasons to use the accessors:

- Whatever you use to document your API (doxygen/PHPdoc/Zend), the generated docs won't show the members that are accessible through magic functions.
- You can document the accessors. You really ought to be able to put a line like this in the documentation: "**IMPORTANT!** This function connects to the database, it will be really slow, use otherFunction() if you can."
- The implementation of the accessor is easily visible for anyone. I wouldn't want to dig into the details of a 200-line magic function to check if the accessor does anything besides setting/getting the value (that's why we're writing accessors after all.)
- You already mentioned the autocompletion of IDEs.
- The __get() function has a well-defined function header, so you won't be able to create getters that return a reference, for example (which is really great when working with arrays, i.e. `$numbers = &$object->getNumbers(); $numbers[] = 4;` - without the reference, you would need to call the setter again.)

Comment: Great points from the voice of experience. I was leaning toward individual accessors before, but now I'm sold. Thanks for your response.

Comment: "Go with the individual accessors for each and every member you want to be accessible from outside" ew, no! Abstraction failure. Go with the individual accessors for each and every _semantic property_ of the object that you want to be accessible from outside. There may be a one-to-one correlation between these notions in your particular use case, or there may not be. An example would be `getX, getY, getZ` vs `getDimensions`.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest difference I see is with phpdoc :

- using `__set`, you will not be able to generate phpdoc for each accessor
- phpdoc being used by moderns IDE, this also means you will not get type-hinting nor code-completion if you use magic-methods *(Using `@property` might help, though, on this point)*.

Personnaly, I would go with defining accessors myself, even if it means writing a bit more code :

- no problem with phpdoc
- you can use whatever parameters and return types you want
- you explicitly indicate which methods can be used
- easier to use specific code for each proerty, without have a really long `__set` method.

Also, I would use those accessor methods when setting properties from inside the class : it means a bit more code, yes -- but it also means going through the specific code (like code to check some stuff) they contain.

Finally, if you are just using some properties to store data, and don't need to define any specific behavior, why not expose them as public, and allow users to access those directly ?

Comment: For the most part I do need to use specific behavior, even if it's simply validating an email address with regex. It wouldn't be a bad idea to use accessors for simple properties anyway -- if you later do need to add specific behavior, you wouldn't have to rewrite the rest of your code to use the accessors instead of using public props directly. (This is where __set() is handy.)

Regarding return type, this question is answered for me in more strongly-typed languages, since I couldn't have one magic method that returns various types. In that sense, __set() is only a cheap shortcut.

Thank you.