# PHP Object Validation

Tags: php, validation, object

I'm currently working on an OO PHP application.  I have a class called validation which I would like to use to check all of the data submitted is valid, however I obviously need somewhere to define the rules for each property to be checked.  At the moment, I'm using arrays during the construction of a new object.  eg:

```
$this->name = array(
'maxlength' => 10,
'minlength' => 2,
'required' => true,
'value' => $namefromparameter
)
```

One array for each property.

I would then call a static method from the validation class which would carry out various checks depending on the values defined in each array.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know the associative array is used commonly to configure things in PHP (it's called [magic container](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer) pattern and is considered bad practice, btw), but why don't you create multiple validator classes instead, each of which able to handle one rule? Something like this:

```
interface IValidator {
    public function validate($value);
}

$validators[] = new StringLengthValidator(2, 10);
$validators[] = new NotNollValidator();
$validators[] = new UsernameDoesNotExistValidator();
```

This has multiple advantages over the implementation using arrays:

- You can *document* them (very important), phpdoc cannot parse comments for array keys.
- Your code becomes typo-safe (`array('reqiured' => true)`)
- It is fully OO and does not introduce new concepts
- It is more readable (although much more verbose)
- The implementation of each constraint can be found intuitively (it's not in a 400-line function, but in the proper class)

**EDIT**: Here is a [link to an answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531091/php-class-def-individual-accessors-mutators-or-set-with-switch/1531158#1531158) to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531091/php-class-def-individual-accessors-mutators-or-set-with-switch), but that is mostly applicable to this one as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of interfaces before.  I'll check them out!

Answer (score 0):

Since using OO it would be cleaner if you used classes for validating properties. E.g.

```
class StringProperty
{
  public $maxLength;
  public $minlength;
  public $required;
  public $value;
  function __construct($value,$maxLength,$minLength,$required)
  {
     $this->value = $value;
     $this-> maxLength = $maxLength;
     $this-> minLength = $minLength;
     $this-> required = $required;
  }
  function isValidat()
  {
    // Check if it is valid
  }
  function getValidationErrorMessage()
  {
  }
}

$this->name = new StringProperty($namefromparameter,10,2,true);
if(!$this->name->isValid())
{
  $validationMessage = $this->name-getValidationErrorMessage();
}
```

Using a class has the advantage of encapsulating logic inside of it that the array (basically a structure) does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get inspired by [Zend-Framework Validation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.validate.html#zend.validate.introduction.definition).

So define a master:

```
class BaseValidator {
    protected $msgs = array();
    protected $params = array();    

    abstract function isValid($value);
    public function __CONSTRUCT($_params) {
         $this->params = $_params;
    }
    public function getMessages() {
         // returns errors-messages
         return $this->msgs;
    }
}
```

And then build your custom validators:

```
class EmailValidator extends BaseValidator {
    public function isValid($val=null) {
        // if no value set use the params['value']
        if ($val==null) {
            $val = $this->params['value'];
        }
        // validate the value
        if (strlen($val) < $this->params['maxlength']) {
            $this->msgs[] = 'Length too short';
        }
        return count($this->msgs) > 0 ? false : true;   
    }
}
```

Finally your inital array could become something like:

```
$this->name = new EmailValidator(
        array(
            'maxlength' => 10,
            'minlength' => 2,
            'required' => true,
            'value' => $namefromparameter,
        ),
    ),
);
```

validation could then be done like this:

```
if ($this->name->isValid()) {
    echo 'everything fine';
} else {
    echo 'Error: '.implode('<br/>', $this->name->getMessages());
}
```